# bash backup script error

Tags: bash, backup

So I'm writing a simple backup script that when called will either back up a specific file or all the files in my current directory into my backup directory.
This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

#verify if $1 is empty, if so, copy all content to backup directory

if [ -z "$1" ]
then

    $files=ls
    #Looping through files
    for file in $files
    do
        cp $file ../backup/
    done      
 #else copy files specified 

else

$files=ls $1

    #Looping through files 
    for file in $files
    do
        cp $file ../backup/
    done
fi
```

and the only error I'm getting is:

> ./backup: line 7: =ls: command not found

I'm not sure why the script won't recognize ls as a command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

to assign a variable, you don't need the dollar sign:

```
files=foo
```

to save the output of an command to a var, you need do:

```
files=$(ls)
```

or

```
files=$(ls /path/to/some/dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try putting the ls into ` marks - better, the back quote. Like this:

```
files=`ls`
```

Here a little background. Check [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html) page for more information about quotation marks in the shell environment:

> The back quote is not used for quoting characters. That character is
>   used for command substitution, where the characters between them are
>   executed by the shell and the results is inserted on that line.

Example:

```
echo the date is `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two mistakes:

1. When you initialize variable "files" you should not prepend it with "$" symbol
2. Command ls should be placed in back quotes (`):

This is a short example:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=`ls`

for file in $files
do
    echo "file: $file"
done
```